# Magnetic Field Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

I've been trying to make some kind of Magnetic Field that sets AddForce towards it. I've found this code somewhere :

```
 else if(collider.tag == "magnet")
     {
         float radius = collider.GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>().radius;
             Vector3 magnetField = collider.transform.position- transform.position;
             float index = (radius - magnetField.magnitude) / radius;
             rigidbody2D.AddForce( -4 * force * magnetField * index);
     }
```

It indeed does set force towards field, but before it happens, if velocity of my character is to small it sets force in opposite direction.Outside the code there is OnTriggerStay2D of course. Could anyone tell me what is going on?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

The source of the issue, assuming that "force" is a positive value representing how strong the magnet is to attract this object, is the -4 in the AddForce method. MagnetField is a vector pointing from the object with the script to the magnet, which is the direction the object should be moving so there is no need to negate it.